# Можно ли получить не валидное значение input c тиом "number"?

Tags: javascript

Можно ли получить не валидное значение input c типом "number" в переменную, которое можно использовать ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

у меня когда то была подобная задача, мол есть числовое поле, и люди по разному могу вводить значения. Решил так: input type=text, через JS запрещал вводить туда что-либо кроме чисел, точки, запятой и минуса, и после ещё раз перед отправкой преобразовывал + валидировал.

Comment: имею ввиду чтобы получить не валидное значение в переменную и чтобы  его можно было дальше использовать

Comment: да, в зависимости от того, с чем вы работаете(pureJs,jquery ....)

Comment: я хочу вставить 10.1 и заменить на 10,1. Но так, как значение не валидно не получается это сделать.

Comment: <input type="number" step="0.01" /> оно?

Comment: неа, пока только кастомный input, больше решений не нашел. С не валидным значением не получается что-то делать, например привести к дробному значению

Comment: перепишите задание! напишите внятно, что есть на входе, основные данные, и что вы хотите на выходе

Comment: Элемент input с типом number имеет атрибут lang, но он не поддерживается всеми браузерами. Можно использовать тип string и атрибут pattern. Например: `<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]+([\.,][0-9][0-9]?)?" title="[Описание формата]" />`. Если input находится в форме, то перед отправкой формы будет выполняться проверка на соответствие значения паттерну.

Comment: да lang не работает нормально, хотелось чтобы не только отправлялось нормально но и помогало пользователю сразу вводить в правильном формате